# Vendor devices produce limitation by MAC address?

Tags: mac-address

Maybe it is silly, but I wonder if the first 3 hexadecimal values in MAC address represent vendor id (in **01:23:45:ff:ff:ff** it is **01:23:45**), is there a limit of **16777215** (**ff:ff:ff**) devices per vendor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first 3 values are called an OUI (organizationally unique identifier) and the last 3 values are called NIC (network interface controller) specific. Most big vendors do have more than one OUI, which removes the 2^24 device limit.